# Last line overflow from PDF

Tags: pdftex, line, overflow

I use a template of a journal.
The last lines of every page overflow from pdf file.
the template link is [here](http://journal.hep.com.cn/UserFiles/File/template09Latex2eFCS.rar)

You can see the problem of page bottom is below;

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you: instead of pointing to the template file, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that replicates the  problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please add MWE which reproduce your problem. Your link to "template" (what is this?) is not reliable.

Comment: I am sorry for my question format. (This is the first question about latex) Thank you for your interest, however I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I changed the parameter in the .sty file and the text fixed the page.

```
\setlength{\textheight}{220truemm} % old version 297mm
```